# Randomize position of animated object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have little script that moves objects on orbital and I want to randomize starting position of object.

Here's what I'm talking about:
http://jsfiddle.net/W69s6/1018/

HTML

```
<div class="orbit">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.orbit
{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.circle
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #00ff00;
    position: absolute;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    orbit('.circle', 0, 0.01, 100, 75, 75);
});

function orbit(obj, t, ts, r, x, y)
{
    t += ts;

    var top = Math.floor(y - (r * Math.sin(t)));
    var left = Math.floor(x - (r * Math.cos(t)));

    $(obj).animate({
        top: top,
        left: left,
    }, 1, function()
    {
        orbit(obj, t, ts, r, x, y);
    });
}
```

Is anyone good at math and knows how to change it?

Comment: randomize starting position of circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first part of your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    orbit('.circle', Math.random()*100, 0.01, 100, 75, 75);
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LDsPJ/ fiddle of his answer.  Works good and is the simplest.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to apply the `Math.random()` the last two arguments since those are the starting X and Y values?

Comment: Because X and Y params will chage orbital position, not circle.

Comment: Work like a charm. Thanks Michael I wouldn't think of that.